# Need help in tuning Group by cube with 6 columns

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle12c, sql-tuning, query-tuning

I want to aggregate data from table1 in all possible combinations of the 6 columns. Table1 has 60Million rows in it. The query is running for more than an hour and still not fetching any data. Need some help in tuning this

```
select /*+ parallel(a,8)*/
    event_date,
         a.COL1,
         COL2,
         COL3,
         COL4,
         COL5,
         COL6,
         count (distinct id) base_count,
         count (distinct case when active_flg = 'Y' then id end) unique_active_cnt,
         count (case when active_flg = 'Y' then id end) active_cnt,
         GROUPING_ID (a.COL1,
                      COL2,
                      COL3,
                      COL4,
                      COL5,
                      COL6)
            AS grp_id
    from table1 partition (P2017_01) a
group by event_date,
         cube (a.COL1,
               COL2,
               COL3,
               COL4,
               COL5,
               COL6);
```

Explain plan for the above sql:-

Explain complete.

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3317440810                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                 
| Id  | Operation                              | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |                                                                                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                 
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                             |   392K|    81M|       | 96682   (4)| 00:00:08 |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION             |                             |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|   2 |   PX COORDINATOR                       |                             |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|   3 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                 | :TQ10001                    |   392K|    20M|       |  1157   (5)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,01 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |                                                                                                                                 
|   4 |     LOAD AS SELECT (TEMP SEGMENT MERGE)| SYS_TEMP_0FDA4B738_9AA210CA |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |                                                                                                                                 
|   5 |      SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP              |                             |   392K|    20M|   293M|  1157   (5)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |                                                                                                                                 
|   6 |       PX RECEIVE                       |                             |  4040K|   208M|       |  1121   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |                                                                                                                                 
|   7 |        PX SEND HASH                    | :TQ10000                    |  4040K|   208M|       |  1121   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,00 | P->P | HASH       |                                                                                                                                 
|   8 |         PX BLOCK ITERATOR              |                             |  4040K|   208M|       |  1121   (2)| 00:00:01 |    25 |    25 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |                                                                                                                                 
|   9 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL             | TABLE1                      |  4040K|   208M|       |  1121   (2)| 00:00:01 |    25 |    25 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  10 |   LOAD AS SELECT                       | SYS_TEMP_0FDA4B738_9AA210CA |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  11 |    PARTITION RANGE SINGLE              |                             |   185K|  9224K|       | 27366   (2)| 00:00:03 |    25 |    25 |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  12 |     SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP               |                             |   185K|  9224K|   278M| 27366   (2)| 00:00:03 |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  13 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | TABLE1                      |  4040K|   196M|       |  8081   (2)| 00:00:01 |    25 |    25 |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  14 |   LOAD AS SELECT                       | SYS_TEMP_0FDA4B738_9AA210CA |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  15 |    PARTITION RANGE SINGLE              |                             | 32686 |  1595K|       | 26191   (2)| 00:00:03 |    25 |    25 |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  16 |     SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP               |                             | 32686 |  1595K|   278M| 26191   (2)| 00:00:03 |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  17 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | TABLE1                      |  4040K|   192M|       |  8081   (2)| 00:00:01 |    25 |    25 |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  18 |   LOAD AS SELECT                       | SYS_TEMP_0FDA4B738_9AA210CA |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  19 |    PARTITION RANGE SINGLE              |                             |    73 |  2336 |       |  8374   (5)| 00:00:01 |    25 |    25 |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  20 |     SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP               |                             |    73 |  2336 |       |  8374   (5)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  21 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | TABLE1                      |  4040K|   123M|       |  8081   (2)| 00:00:01 |    25 |    25 |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  22 |   LOAD AS SELECT                       | SYS_TEMP_0FDA4B738_9AA210CA |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  23 |    PARTITION RANGE SINGLE              |                             | 15408 |   707K|       |  8374   (5)| 00:00:01 |    25 |    25 |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  24 |     SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP               |                             | 15408 |   707K|       |  8374   (5)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  25 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | TABLE1                      |  4040K|   181M|       |  8081   (2)| 00:00:01 |    25 |    25 |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  26 |   LOAD AS SELECT                       | SYS_TEMP_0FDA4B738_9AA210CA |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  27 |    PARTITION RANGE SINGLE              |                             |    34 |   986 |       |  8374   (5)| 00:00:01 |    25 |    25 |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  28 |     SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP               |                             |    34 |   986 |       |  8374   (5)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  29 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | TABLE1                      |  4040K|   111M|       |  8081   (2)| 00:00:01 |    25 |    25 |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  30 |   LOAD AS SELECT                       | SYS_TEMP_0FDA4B738_9AA210CA |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  31 |    PARTITION RANGE SINGLE              |                             |     6 |   168 |       |  8374   (5)| 00:00:01 |    25 |    25 |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  32 |     SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP               |                             |     6 |   168 |       |  8374   (5)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  33 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | TABLE1                      |  4040K|   107M|       |  8081   (2)| 00:00:01 |    25 |    25 |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  34 |   LOAD AS SELECT                       | SYS_TEMP_0FDA4B738_9AA210CA |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  35 |    PARTITION RANGE SINGLE              |                             |     3 |    75 |       |  8374   (5)| 00:00:01 |    25 |    25 |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  36 |     SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP               |                             |     3 |    75 |       |  8374   (5)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  37 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | TABLE1                      |  4040K|    96M|       |  8081   (2)| 00:00:01 |    25 |    25 |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  38 |   PX COORDINATOR                       |                             |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  39 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                 | :TQ20000                    |   392K|    81M|       |    97   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |                                                                                                                                 
|  40 |     VIEW                               |                             |   392K|    81M|       |    97   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  41 |      PX BLOCK ITERATOR                 |                             |   392K|    20M|       |    97   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,00 | PCWC |            |                                                                                                                                 
|  42 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                | SYS_TEMP_0FDA4B738_9AA210CA |   392K|    20M|       |    97   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |                                                                                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                 

Note                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
-----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   - Degree of Parallelism is 8 because of table property                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

53 rows selected.
```

Comment: Can you share the SQL Monitor report.

Comment: Sorry BobC we do not have access to that here

Comment: OK. Can you at least get the execution plan. Can you run: select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, 'TYPICAL' ) )

Comment: @BobC I have added the explain plan.

Comment: Which database version is this? Can you also try (or at least do the explain plan) without the two COUNT( DISTINCT's .. )

Comment: @BobC We are using "Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production". 
I removed the COUNT(DISTINCT's..) and run the query again. It got finished in 01:18min. So its the COUNT(DISTINCT's..) that is causing the pain.
But I need the distinct counts as well, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you try using the  APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT

Comment: @BobC But I require exact counts not any approximation of that

Comment: I want to see if the Approx will perform faster.

Comment: @BobC: Yes APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT did perform faster. It took ~12mins to complete. But as I was telling I would be requiring exact DISTINCT COUNTs here. Can that be achieved somehow?

Comment: Do you really need a cube? With 6 columns, that is 64 combinations. The other option you have, would be to re-write the query, which might give you better performance.

Comment: @BobC Yes... I do require 64 combinations of the 6 columns.... How do you propose to rewrite the query?

Comment: You would need to write that would essentially be each dimension you need to group by and then UNION ALL them. If you need an example of how to do that, let me know.

Comment: I did try that also.... 64 different GROUP BYs combined with UNION ALLs.... but still it is not fetching data after running for more than 1hour

Comment: Can you determine which ones are fast and which are slow?  Can you get a SQL Monitor report?